# Coupling EF Core migrations with product release versions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm new to EF Core migration tool. I'm looking for similar functionality that Liquibase has where we can define set of migrations to a single file so that they can be grouped and migrated one by one as a set. This would give us the chance from rollbacking or upgrading from one product version to another (101.1.03 to 101.1.14). So all the changes are applied from 101.1.03 to 101.1.14. I also do not no how to do this programmatically. This should be a lot common scenario but could not find how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this functionality exists out of the box.

I think it's for another discussion, but I would suggest handling it with code versioning.

Comment: but shouldn't that be common as many applications need this?